# p:commandButton mull functioning

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces, commandbutton

`p:commandButton` have no method to call in `actionListener`. I have just used it for hiding dialog `editSensorDialog` But its calling the method `addDeviceMappings` in `p:selectOneMenu`'s `valueChangeListener`.

any thing wrong in my code, why `p:commandButton` calling unnecessary?

Complete code of above issue :

```
    <p:dialog id="editSensorDialog" style="width: 360px;" width="360" height="400"
              modal="true" widgetVar="editSensorDialog" resizable="false" >

      <p:dataTable id="editSensorList" value="#{sensorController.sensorsMappingList}"
                   var="item" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">

         <p:column headerText="#{bundle['label.Sensor']}" id="editdeviceName">    
           <h:outputText rendered="false" value="#{item.value}"/> 
           <p:selectOneMenu valueChangeListener="#{sensorController.addDeviceMappings}"> 
             <p:ajax update="@this"/>
             <f:selectItems value="#{item.value}" var="sensor" itemLabel="#{sensor}"
                            itemValue="#{item.name}+#{sensor}"/>
           </p:selectOneMenu>
         </p:column>

     <f:facet name="footer">  
       <p:commandButton value="#{bundle['label.Submit']}"
                        onsuccess="editSensorDialog.hide()"/>
     </f:facet> 
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way would be to change your JavaScript from `onsuccess` to `onclick` and stop propagation.

```
<p:commandButton value="#{bundle['label.Submit']}" onclick="editSensorDialog.hide();return false;"/>
```

Also, usage of a `p:commandButton` is a bit overkill for that task, any plain HTML element will do the job (`<input type="button" value="#{bundle['label.Submit']}" />` or `<a>#{bundle['label.Submit']}</a>` etc.

Comment: I have used 1st solution
Thank you very much @Alexandre Lavoie

Comment: But its not efficient solution yet. Dialog should hide onsuccess of process.